# Securing data in the google app engine datastore

Tags: python, security, google-app-engine, rsa, sha

Our google app engine app stores a fair amount of personally identifying information (email, ssn, etc) to identify users. I'm looking for advice as to how to secure that data.

### My current strategy

**Store the sensitive data in two forms:**

- Hashed - using SHA-2 and a salt
- Encrypted - using public/private key RSA

**When we need to do look ups:**

- Do look-ups on the hashed data (hash the PII in a query, compare it to the hashed PII in the datastore).

**If we ever need to re-hash the data or otherwise deal with it in a raw form:**

- Decrypt the encrypted version with our private key. Never store it in raw form, just process it then re-hash & re-encrypt it.

### My concerns

**Keeping our hash salt secret**

If an attacker gets ahold of the data in the datastore, as well as our hash salt, I'm worried they could brute force the sensitive data. Some of it (like SSN, a 9-digit number) does not have a big key space, so even with a modern hash algorithm I believe it could be done if the attacker knew the salt.

My current idea is to keep the salt out of source control and in it's own file. That file gets loaded on to GAE during deployment and the app reads the file when it needs to hash incoming data.

In between deployments the salt file lives on a USB key protected by an angry bear (or a safe deposit box).

With the salt only living in two places

1. The USB key
2. Deployed to google apps

and with code download permanently disabled, I can't think of a way for someone to get ahold of the salt without stealing that USB key. Am I missing something?

**Keeping our private RSA key secret**

Less worried about this. It will be rare that we'll need to decrypt the encrypted version (only if we change the hash algorithm or data format).

The private key never has to touch the GAE server, we can pull down the encrypted data, decrypt it locally, process it, and re-upload the encrypted / hashed versions.

We can keep our RSA private key on a USB stick guarded by a bear AND a tiger, and only bring it out when we need it.

---

I realize this question isn't exactly google apps specific, but I think GAE makes the situation somewhat unique.

If I had total control, I'd do things like lock down deployment access and access to the datastore viewer with two-factor authentication, but those options aren't available at the moment (Having a GAE specific password is good, but I like having RSA tokens involved).

I'm also neither a GAE expert nor a security expert, so if there's a hole I'm missing or something I'm not thinking of specific to the platform, I would love to hear it.

Comment: you will need to make sure that remote_api is not enabled.

Comment: Will definitely do that @shayerlichmen, but what worries me is that if someone gets admin rights they could turn remote_api on even if I've previously disabled it.

Comment: salts are not secret! A salt is a random value added to each piece of hashed data - a different one for each element - used to prevent precomputation attacks. If it's the same for every piece of data, and a secret, it's a key - and you should be using HMAC, not a raw hash function.

Comment: Also, you _can_ lock down deployment access and datastore access with two-factor authentication: Just require that everyone who has admin access to your app has two-factor authentication enabled on their Google account.

Comment: Thanks @NickJohnson, didn't realize that two-factor worked for deployments as well. Enabling two-factor right now!

Comment: @Rob Hi Rob, I know this comes years late, but I wonder how did you manage to keep your secret key out of version control and ONLY include it when uploading to appengine. I am thinking of using a second module for this and have the main module fetch the secret from that 'secret guard module'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When deciding on a security architecture, the first thing in your mind should always be threat models. Who are your potential attackers, what are their capabilities, and how can you defend against them? Without a clear idea of your threat model, you've got no way to assess whether or not your proposed security measures are sufficient, or even if they're necessary.

From your text, I'm guessing you're seeking to protect against some subset of the following:

1. An attacker who compromises your datastore data, but not your application code.
2. An attacker who obtains access to credentials to access the admin console of your app and can deploy new code.

For the former, encrypting or hashing your datastore data is likely sufficient (but see the caveats later in this answer). Protecting against the latter is tougher, but as long as your admin users can't execute arbitrary code without deploying a new app version, storing your keys in a module that's not checked in to source control, as you suggest, ought to work just fine, since even with admin access, they can't recover the keys, nor can they deploy a new version that reveals the keys to them. Make sure to disable downloading of source, obviously.

You rightly note some concerns about hashing of data with a limited amount of entropy - and you're right to be concerned. To some degree, salts can help with this by preventing precomputation attacks, and key stretching, such as that employed in PBKDF2, scrypt, and bcrypt, can make your attacker's life harder by increasing the amount of work they have to do. However, with something like SSN, your keyspace is simply so small that no amount of key stretching is going to help - if you hash the data, and the attacker gets the hash, they will be able to determine the original SSN.

In such situations, your only viable approach is to encrypt the data with a secret key. Now your attacker is forced to brute-force the key in order to get the data, a challenge that is orders of magnitude harder.

In short, my recommendation would be to encrypt your data using a standard (private key) cipher, with the key stored in a module not in source control. Using hashing instead will only weaken your data, while using public key cryptography doesn't provide appreciable security against any plausible threat model that you don't already have by using a standard cipher.

Of course, the number one way to protect your users' data is to not store it in the first place, if you can. :)

Comment: Thanks @Nick, that's super helpful. Sadly, not storing the data is not an option, it's core to our business model =)

Comment: Great point that if it's the same everywhere and secret, it's a key. Hashing was appealing because it was easy to run a query - I hash the incoming request data with the salt(fine, key) and compare it against the hashed data in the datastore. But if I have a cipher that delivers consistent ciphertext, that would work as well. I do worry about having the key to unlock the data and the data itself all living on app engine at once... I felt good to know that even if someone got our datastore and code, they'd at least have to do SOME work to brute-force the hashed data.

Answer (score 3):

You can increase your hashing algorithm security by using HMAC, a secret key, and a unique salt per entry (I know people will disagree with me on this but it's my belief from my research that it helps avoid certain attacks). You can also use bcrypt or scrypt to hash which will make reversing the hash an extremely time consuming process (but you'll also have to factor this in as time it takes your app to compute the hash).

By disabling code downloads and keeping your secret key protected, I can't imagine how someone can get a hold of it. Just make sure your code is kept protected under similar safe guards or that you remove the secret key from your code during development and only pull it out to deploy. I assume you will keep your secret key in your code (I've heard many people say to keep it in memory to be ultra secure but given the nature of AppEngine and instances, this isn't feasible).

Update:
Be sure to enable 2-factor authentication for all Google accounts that have admin rights to your app. Google offers this so not sure if your restriction for enabling this was imposed by an outside force or not.

Comment: Google does allow 2-factor authentication for accounts, but sadly not for google app engine.

Comment: @RobBoyle Yes it does! If your account is using 2-factor auth, you either have to use an app-specific password, or you can go through the standard 2-factor dance by passing the `--oauth2` flag to `appcfg.py`.

Comment: Whoa! That's cool, I didn't notice the --oauth2 flag. That's awesome. Thanks @NickJohnson.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting approach to encrypt data on a datastore. After going through this, one question that comes to my mind is how do you query data on your hashes? Are you using comparison of two hashes or more fine grained hashing? Again how do you accomplish operations like greater than value, less than value after hashing and encrypting the data in your table?

[Fine grained hashing](http://harisankar-krishnaswamy.blogspot.in/2013/07/securing-data-on-appengine-and-other.html) meaning, do you hash consecutive bytes of a data stream to get the accumulated hash. i.e hash(abcd) = hash(a,b) + hash (b,c) + etc. This type of hashing would tell how similar the underlying data are rather than a match.

Comment: We were just doing simple exact matches, we didn't need to do any sort of sorting; so just straight comparison.